# Excepción al procesar la página JSP

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11

[image: Imagen de error]

Me sale ese error, a otro compañero le mande el código y normal le funciona. Por favor ayuda con ese problema. Utilizo jdk 11, Apache NetBeans 12.3 y Tomcat versión 10.0

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor, añade mas información a tu pregunta para que los usuarios te puedan ayudar. Se necesita algo de código para `comenzar` a entender cual es tu problema. De todas formas, te genera un error en el archivo `enviarCorreo.jsp` en la `linea 17`. Revisa eso!

Comment: Por favor también comparte ese archivo donde esta la linea de error